# Huge font size in Java VisualVM

Tags: java, fonts, gnome

I use GNOME Shell 3.12.2 and set all my fonts to size 11 but Java VisualVM somehow uses an extremely large font. How can I change that?[image]

**VisualVM Details**

```
Version: 
1.8.0 (Build 1360-130911); platform 20130911-unknown-revn
System: 
Linux (3.16.4-1-ARCH) , amd64 64bit
Java: 
1.8.0; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b70, mixed mode)
Vendor: 
Oracle Corporation, http://java.oracle.com/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem doesn't occur any more on Gnome Shell 3.22.1 in VisualVM 1.3.8 but I can't say which version and which of the two was the culprit.